# Oracle SQL Error PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NOOFCUSTOMERS'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to create a trigger to add 'NoOfCustomers' into the STORE table. If the number of customers is greater than the limit then it will display an error message. I'm getting the error "bad bind variable 'NEW.NOOFCUSTOMERS'" when trying to run the trigger and I can't seem to work out why.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NoOfCustomersTrigger 
      BEFORE INSERT ON STORE
      FOR EACH ROW 
      DECLARE V_CAPACITY SHOPS.LIMIT%TYPE;
    BEGIN 
          SELECT LIMIT INTO V_LIMIT
          FROM SHOPS, SERVES
          WHERE CUSTID = SERVES.CUSTID AND STORENO = :NEW.STORENO;
          IF (:NEW.NOOFCUSTOMERS > V_LIMIT) THEN 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20004,'The Number of Customers exceeds the LIMIT'); 
          END IF; 
        END;
```

Comment: I just realised, do I need to have NOOFCUSTOMERS created in it already?

Comment: Are you asking whether you need the `NOOFCUSTOMERS` to pre-exist in the table? Since pl/SQL code evaluates table structure at compile time, the answer is yes.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out just after I asked. Now I have two errors :        1) PL/SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined                                2) PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: ORA-00918 means, that column with the same name exists in both tables - add prefixes to columns: `tablename.columnname` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some errors in your code,

1. Use `V_LIMIT` in declare section instead of `V_CAPACITY`, as you are using `v_limit` in you code.
2. The sql statement will throw `column ambiguously defined` error, Columns must be referenced as TABLE.COLUMN_NAME or TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN_NAME.

Try like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER noofcustomerstrigger 
      BEFORE INSERT ON STORE
      FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE v_limit shops.LIMIT%TYPE;
BEGIN 
     SELECT LIMIT INTO v_limit
     FROM shops A, serves b
     WHERE A.custid = b.custid AND storeno = :NEW.storeno;

     IF (:NEW.noofcustomers > v_limit) THEN 
          raise_application_error (-20004,'The Number of Customers exceeds the LIMIT'); 
     END IF; 
END;
```